# How do I send an event to a component?

Tags: codenameone

I have a button btn that doSomething() in response to a long-pressed event.

```
    Button btn = new Button("do Something button");
    btn.addLongPressListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                doSomething();
        }
        
    });
```

How do I send a long-pressed event to btn by code?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal since "long press" is a bit of a hack. Ideally you should try to provide a generic API call and just invoke that instead of sending an event.

The simplest approach is to invoke the `Form.longPointerPress(x, y)` method roughly like this:

```
frm.longPointerPress(cmp.getAbsoluteX(), cmp.getAbsoluteY());
```

Comment: I would like to press a button(btnx) contained by a container(cnt) by programming.
I invoke the cnt.PointerPress(btnx.getAbsoluteX(), btnx.getAbsoluteY()) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I should use addPointerPressedListener not addActionListener. But what is the difference between those two listeners?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77772339/what-are-the-diffenences-between-addpointerpressed-and-addactionlistener